# Panoramio api for searching by tag

Tags: panoramio

I am in developing web application to allow user search Panoramio images using a tag. Would be appreciate if someone has done previously and share how you do that to me.

Comment: Try it yourself and when you get stuck, ask a specific question. Asking people to do things for you is not appropriate on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find all the information you need to know here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-panoramio-tags

Its easy to implement, give it a go. As long as you've set up the Panoramio service correctly, it should only take a line or two of code.